# НЕ могу вывести цены по убыванию laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, не могу вывести цены по убыванию
Мой контроллер

```
public function category(Category $category){
    $categories = Category::where('active', 1)->get();
    $products = Product::orderBy('price', 'desc')->get();
//  dd($products);
//  dd($category->$products);
    return view('pages.products', compact('category', 'categories', 'products'));
}
```

Мой шаблон:

```
<div class="product_sidebar flex">
@if($category->products)
    @if($category->products->count())
        @foreach($category->products as $product)                    
            <div class="product_card">
                <a href="{{ route('category.index3', [$product->category, $product]) }}" class="pop_pro">
                    <div class="product_item">
                        <div class="flex column"><span class="code_num">{{ $product->article }}</span>
                        <style>
                            img.product-img {
                                width: 100%;
                                height: 200px;
                            }                                                
                        </style>
                        <img src="{{ Voyager::image($product->image) }}" alt="" class="product-img"></div>
                        <div class="prod_info">
                        {{--<span>{{ $product->title }}</span>--}}
                        <h4>{{ $product->title }}</h4>
                        <div class="product_attr flex">
                            <div class="flex column char"><span class="attr_name">{{ $product->specification1 }}</span><span class="attr_quan">{{ $product->specification2 }}</span></div>
                            <div class="flex column char"><span class="attr_name">{{ $product->specification3 }}</span><span class="attr_quan">{{ $product->specification4 }}</span></div>
                            <div class="flex column char"><span class="attr_name">{{ $product->specification5 }}</span><span class="attr_quan">{{ $product->specification6 }}</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex last_line">
                            <span class="price">{{ $product->price }} тг.</span>
                            <a data-fancybox href="{{ $product->youtube }}" class="youtube flex"><img src="{{ asset('build/img/youtube_icon.svg') }}"><span>Видео</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#modal_window" class="fancybox_modal" data-product="{{ $product->title }}"><div class="btn2">Заказать</div></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endif
```

Моя модель:

```
public function category()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Помогите

Comment: `orderBy('created_at', 'asc')` - это что? попытка ваывести цены по убыванию даты добавления?

Comment: да я думал вывести их по последней дате, но ничего не получилось

Comment: так что надо-то в итоге? По убыванию цены или даты добавления?

Comment: исправил, по убыванию

Comment: И что означает "не могу"? Какое-то визуальное проявление у этого "не могу" есть?

Comment: Не могу означает выводит дефолтом

Comment: Пробовали через orderByRaw? (`orderByRaw('price DESC')`)

Comment: Вангую что поле цены текстовое. Почему оно не сортируется как числовое? Ииииинтееереееснооо...

Comment: ну он даже по id не вытаскивает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public function category(Category $category){
    $category->load(['products' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('price', 'desc');
    }]);
    $categories = Category::where('active', 1)->get();
    $products = Product::orderBy('price', 'desc')->get();
    return view('pages.products', compact('category', 'categories', 'products'));
}
```